# Iterate through multiple list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I would like to iterate through list of dictionaries in order to get a specific value, but I can't figure it out.

I've made a simplified version of what I've been working with. These lists or much longer, with more dictionaries in them, but for the sake of an example, I hope this shortened dataset will be enough.

```
listOfResults = [{"29":2523,"30":626,"10":0,"32":128},{"29":2466,"30":914,"10":0,"32":69}]
```

For example, I need the values of the key "30" from the dictionaries above. I've managed to get those and stored them in a list of integers. ( [626, 914] )

These integers are basically IDs. After this, I need to get the value of these IDs from another list of dictionaries.

```
listOfTrack = [{"track_length": 1.26,"track_id": 626,"track_name": "Rainbow Road"},{"track_length": 6.21,"track_id": 914,"track_name": "Excalibur"}]
```

I would like to print/store the track_names and track_lengths of the IDs I've got from the listOfResults earlier. Unfortunately, I've ended up in a complete mess of for loops.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Give a [mre], not a vague description of _"a complete mess"_.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
ids = [626, 914]
result = { track for track in list_of_tracks if track.get("track_id") in ids }
```

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately can't comment on the answer given by Nathaniel Ford because I'm a new user so I just thought I'd share it here as an answer.

His answer is basically correct, but I believe you need to replace the curly braces with brackets or else you will get this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

The answer should look like:

```
ids = [626, 914]
result = [track for track in listOfTrack if track.get("track_id") in ids]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfResults = [{"29":2523,"30":626,"10":0,"32":128},{"29":2466,"30":914,"10":0,"32":69}]

ids = [x.get('30') for x in listOfResults]

listOfTrack = [{"track_length": 1.26,"track_id": 626,"track_name": "Rainbow Road"},{"track_length": 6.21,"track_id": 914,"track_name": "Excalibur"}]

out = [x for x in listOfTrack if x.get('track_id') in ids]
```

---

Alternatively, it may be time to learn a new library if you're going to be doing a lot this.

```
import pandas as pd

results_df = pd.DataFrame(listOfResults)
track_df = pd.DataFrame(listOfTrack)
```

These Look like:

```
# results_df
     29   30  10   32
0  2523  626   0  128
1  2466  914   0   69

# track_df
   track_length  track_id    track_name
0          1.26       626  Rainbow Road
1          6.21       914     Excalibur
```

Now we can answer your question:

```
# Creates a mask of rows where this is True.
mask = track_df['track_id'].isin(results_df['30'])
# Specifies that we want just those two columns.
cols = ['track_length', 'track_name']
out = track_df.loc[mask, cols]
print(out)

# Or we can make it back into a dictionary:
print(out.to_dict('records'))
```

Output:

```
   track_length    track_name
0          1.26  Rainbow Road
1          6.21     Excalibur

[{'track_length': 1.26, 'track_name': 'Rainbow Road'}, {'track_length': 6.21, 'track_name': 'Excalibur'}]
```